# get div corners pixel positions after rotation

Tags: javascript, css

how can i calculate top-left, bottom-left, top-right, bottom-right pixel positions of a div after you have set a rotation radian/degree on it?

An example would be helpful.

Comment: you can't calculate the corners unless you know what the center of rotation was.

Comment: Could you build a use case (in jsfiddle or other) so we can identify your exact aim

Comment: The answer you have accepted is completely incorrect.

Comment: Are you still sure the answer you have accepted is correct? Did it work for you?

Comment: I've updated my accepted answer to my own solution I got worked out. This works for me and return correct results.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This solved my issue with calculating new pixel positions after rotating. I created a function to be used, passing in the x/y position, half width/height of the div and the new rotation angle.

```
function getPixelsByAngle(x,y,halfWidth,halfHeight,angle){
   var bounds = [
      //upper left
      [x + (halfWidth) * Math.cos(angle) - (halfHeight) * Math.sin(angle) + halfWidth, y + (halfHeight) * Math.cos(angle) + (halfWidth) * Math.sin(angle) + halfHeight],
      //upper right
      [x - (halfWidth) * Math.cos(angle) - (halfHeight) * Math.sin(angle) + halfWidth, y + (halfHeight) * Math.cos(angle) - (halfWidth) * Math.sin(angle) + halfHeight],
      //bottom right
      [x - (halfWidth) * Math.cos(angle) + (halfHeight) * Math.sin(angle) + halfWidth, y - (halfHeight) * Math.cos(angle) - (halfWidth) * Math.sin(angle) + halfHeight],
      //bottom left
      [x + (halfWidth) * Math.cos(angle) + (halfHeight) * Math.sin(angle) + halfWidth, y - (halfHeight) * Math.cos(angle) + (halfWidth) * Math.sin(angle) + halfHeight]
   ];
   return bounds;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate for you to use the information I gave and then roll it into a (poorly written) answer and then accept that instead

Answer (score 12):

Assuming rotation *relative to the center* and coordinates of the four corners also relative to that same origin, each point `(±a, ±b)` where `a` and `b` are the half-width and half-height of the div needs to be multiplied by the transformation matrix:

```
|  cos(theta)   -sin(theta) |
|  sin(theta)    cos(theta) |
```

e.g.:

```
x' = a * cos(theta) - b * sin(theta)
y' = a * sin(theta) + b * cos(theta)
```

NB: the above is for cartesian coordinates - invert the `theta` terms as necessary for DOM coordinates where the `y` axis runs downwards.

Answer (score 8):

I was confused about the answers here. The down-voted answer is definitely wrong but I also struggled with the other answer because it's a very good but very pure hint. The example there is still very theoretical for a usual web developer. So I combined both answers and made a working version of the down-voted example. So for those who also search for a working javascript solution. Here it is:

```
function getPixelsByAngle(x, y, width, height, angle) {
   var radians = angle * Math.PI / 180;
   return [
      //upper left
      [x + width/2 + width/-2 * Math.cos(radians) - height/-2 * Math.sin(radians), y + height/2 + width/-2 * Math.sin(radians) + height/-2 * Math.cos(radians)],
      //upper right
      [x + width/2 + width/2 * Math.cos(radians) - height/-2 * Math.sin(radians), y + height/2 + width/2 * Math.sin(radians) + height/-2 * Math.cos(radians)],
      //bottom right
      [x + width/2 + width/2 * Math.cos(radians) - height/2 * Math.sin(radians), y + height/2 + width/2 * Math.sin(radians) + height/2 * Math.cos(radians)],
      //bottom left
      [x + width/2 + width/-2 * Math.cos(radians) - height/2 * Math.sin(radians), y + height/2 + width/-2 * Math.sin(radians) + height/2 * Math.cos(radians)],
   ];
}
```

Comment: Are the x/y params the coordinates for the center of the given element?

Comment: Bumping this, is x/y the center?

Comment: No, x/y is the position of the upper left corner of the element. So it indicates the position of the element on a coordinate system. So the result contains also positions on that coordinate system. However, x and y are actually not needed for the calculation. You can simply remove the x and y variables from the whole function and you'll only get the distance the corners have moved with the rotation.
The rotation point is always the center of the element.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This one saved me a lot of time - and works!

Comment: Great function, works very well